# Solving the following recurrence equation involving polynomials.

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, recurrence-relations

From a problem I have I derived the following equation

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\left(2k + 1\right)xP_k(x) + (1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}P_k(x) = P_{k+1}(x) \\
P_1(x)=1
\end{array}
\right. .
$$

The equation is derived by my guess that for all $k \geq 1$
$$
\frac{d^k}{dx^k} \arcsin(x) = \frac{1}{\left(1-x^2\right)^{k+\frac{1}{2}}} P_k(x)
$$
Where $P_k(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1$.
(I suppose that you can prove it by induction).

Is there a way you can suggest me to solve that equation? The purpose would be basically find all the coefficients of $P_k$ for given $k$.

Update : Attempt I made

I think I've derived a recurrence relationship for $P_k(x)$ Let's consider the relationship

$$
\left(2k - 1\right)xP_{k-1}(x) + (1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}P_{k-1}(x) = P_{k}(x)
$$

Let's express
$$
P_k(x)= \sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_{j,k}x^j, \;\; a_{j,k}=0 \;\; \forall j < 0, j > k - 1
$$
Substituing in recurrence we get
$$
\sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty} \left[ \left(2k -j\right)a_{j-1,k-1} + \left(j+1 \right)a_{j+1,k-1}\right]x^j = \sum_{j=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_{j,k}x^j
$$
To be equal the two polynomial it must be verified that
$$
\left(2k -j\right)a_{j-1,k-1} + \left(j+1 \right)a_{j+1,k-1} = a_{j,k}
$$

What puzzles me in the relantionship above is that the $j$-th coefficient of $P_k$ depends from the coefficient $j+1$-th of $P_{k-1}$ do you think there's some mistakes in my derivation?

I used series instead of summation because it makes easier to handle boundary conditions.

Comment: I checked your derivation, it is OK. The puzzling relationship was caused by the summand $\frac{d}{dx}P_{k-1}(x)$ at the left hand side.